# Hierarchical clustering with precomputed cosine similarity matrix using scikit learn produces error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering, cosine-distance

We want to use cosine similarity with hierarchical clustering and we have cosine similarities already calculated.
In the sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering documentation it says:

> A distance matrix (instead of a similarity matrix) is needed as input
>   for the fit method.

So, we converted cosine similarities to distances as

```
distance = 1 - similarity
```

Our python code produces error at the `fit()` method at the end. (I am not writing the real value of `X` in the code, since it is very big.) X is just a cosine similarity matrix with values converted to distance as written above. Notice the diagonal, it is all 0.) Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

X = np.array([[0,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0,0.7],[0.4,0.7,0]])

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed')  
cluster.fit(X)
```

The error is:

```
runfile('/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b8b98765b168>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr')

  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 100, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr/untitled0.py", line 84, in <module>
    cluster.fit(X)

  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py", line 795, in fit
    (self.affinity, ))

ValueError: precomputed was provided as affinity. Ward can only work with euclidean distances.
```

Is there anything that I can provide? Thanks already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [sklearn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html):

> If linkage is “ward”, only “euclidean” is accepted. If
>   “precomputed”, a distance matrix (instead of a similarity matrix) is
>   needed as input for the fit method.

So you need to change the linkage to one of complete, average or single. If you try this it works:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

X = np.array([[0,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0,0.7],[0.4,0.7,0]])

#cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed', linkage='complete') 
#cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed', linkage='average')
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed', linkage='single')
cluster.fit(X)
```

Comment: Looks like it. Thank you for your time. My results are not satisfying. Is the format of input matrix correct if I ask? Label results: ```[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]```

Comment: @M.Kaan You have to set the Threshold distance here. And set it a bit less than you normally set while euclidean. This will work for sure.

Comment: @M.Kaan I was having the same issue. Then i set distance_threshold=0.3 and it is working now

Comment: @lil-wolf Why "a bit less"?

Comment: @jtlz2  cosine similarity and distance work different way than what people do in Euclidean distance world. (I would call it ideal world) . so choosing less threshold worked for me. (i don't remember much). This is just my observation. One thing you can do is just to observe your distances by taking one example and try to do some manual brain usage and should set threshold accordingly.

Comment: @lil-wolf Thanks - I just wondering whether it was due to dimensionality.

Comment: @jtlz2 yeah. maybe you're right. 
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-surprising-behaviour-of-distance-metrics-in-high-dimensions-c2cb72779ea6

Comment: @lil-wolf Nice - thanks for the piece!